# .Net Add Scaffolding Identity Error running selected code generator

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

Blazor on .net8.0 VS2022

While attempting to add new scafolding pages, I receive a dialog with
"Error There was an error running the seleced code generator: 'Failed to compile the project in memory' with a list of:
CS0115 'OnInitialized(): no suitable method found to override',
CS0115 'OnInitializedAsync(): no suitable method found to override',
CS0103: The  name '_dbContext' does not exist in the current context

For each page with the OnItialized, or _dbContext is used.

The project does build and run normally in debugging, and when published, but these errors pop up every time I attempt to add a scaffolding item.

.proj File

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId></UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="CurrieTechnologies.Razor.SweetAlert2" Version="5.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid.EntityFrameworkAdapter" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MudBlazor" Version="6.11.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Common" Version="6.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Protocol" Version="6.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.RegularExpressions" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
    <Folder Include="Pages\Player\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have tried cleaning the project. Deleting both bin and obj folders.  The project continues to build and run properly in debugging, but does not allow for new Identity scaffolding items to be added.

Comment: If your code is not based off a template anymore it will not work. I have on occasion created a dummy project with the same namespaces and scaffolded that to copy paste the code across.